# CMOS/RTC battery standard connector type?

Tags: batteries, connector, wiring, wire-terminals

Most CMOS/RTC batteries have a standard connector type, however after exhausting tons of time searching I cannot seem to find the type of connector these use.

It's a 2 pin connector with 1.25mm pitch. It reminds me of a JST type connector however it's not that, and I've also search to see if it was apart of any molex mini series. Pictures for reference:

I'm looking for connector B in this picture, connector A seems to be a JST-SH 1.0mm pitch.

[image]

Another example:

[image]

Comment: Readily available at Digikey but crimp pins or with 2” wires are separate items

Comment: @TonyStewartolderthandirt would you happen to have a model number, part type or anything? I already know they're available somewhere.

Comment: I just pasted your description into their search window

Answer (score 2):

The 2”wire pair with crimp pin sockets may be easily searched , then compare dwg. Dimensions for polarized tabs and housing then choose mating crimp pin sockets with 2” wires for ease of use.

https://www.digikey.com/products/en/connectors-interconnects/rectangular-connectors-housings/319?keywords=&sort=&pv88=2&pv89=108

D-K , Mouser etc have excellent search filters but connectors like this tend to be unique and IP protected for some time for copy protection. So often 2nd sources are rare.

I used to specialize in sourcing hard to get high volume connectors and for 500$ MOQ , AUK connectors in TW did a pretty good job.

Comment: This is not the right socket, it's 1.25mm pitch not 1.0mm pitch

Comment: "It's a 2 pin connector with 1.25mm pitch - I'm looking for connector B in this picture"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's a MPN connector from Molex's picoblade series. Still not entirely sure. The Intel NUC board has the connector I'm looking for and the part number is listed as 85205-0200 and the one listed below is slightly different but with same dimensions. Link to an eaglepcb library with a footprint/symbol aswell.

https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/molex-llc/51021-0200/WM1720-ND/242842

https://github.com/ProjectInABox/pib_eagle_libraries/blob/master/PiB_batteries.lbr#L796